# Jenkins pipeline menu does not show the "Configure", "Build Now", and some other options

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins pipeline that I have setup with a project I have on GitHub. Initially, I manually initiated a build each time I changed my code by clicking the "Build Now" option. However, I did two things to make my process easier:

- I setup a GitHub hook to run the build I defined in my Jenkinsfile after each push to my master branch
- I setup a periodic build to build every hour

I left my Jenkins for a day, came back, and everything, even from the dashboard, looks different.

For example:

My dashboard used to have these options:

- New Item
- People
- Build History
- Project Relationship
- Check File Fingerprint
- Manage Jenkins
- My Views
- Lockable Resources
- Credentials
- New View

The current dashboard only has three of those options:

- People
- Build History
- Credentials

Also, when I clicked on my pipeline, the options I had were:

- Status
- Changes
- Build Now
- Delete Pipeline
- Configure
- Full Stage View
- Rename
- Pipeline Syntax

Whereas now, they are:

- Status
- Full Stage View
- GitHub Hook Log
- Git Polling Log

How can I change my configurations/settings to see the pages the way I saw them before? It seems I can't create any new items or change my current pipeline, which are things I may need to do in the future.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I wasn't logged in. I didn't think the initial pages would even show up if I hadn't been logged in, so I didn't even consider it to be a possibility. I logged in and all my issues were resolved.